# Delete row/column from numpy array if all its elements equal a certain value

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, delete-row

I'm trying to find a succint way of going over all rows and all columns of a numpy array, and deleting a row or column if all of its values are equal to, for example, `inf`.

Let's say I have the following array:

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
             [np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf],
             [9,10,11,12]])
```

Then if I use,

```
row = 0
while row < m.shape[0]:
    if np.all(np.isinf(m[row,:])):
        m = np.delete(m,row,axis=0)
        row -= 1
    row += 1

print(m)
```

I get the output of,

```
[[1,2,3,4],     
[9,10,11,12]]
```

I can use a similar method to delete a column of all `infs`. However, this method is quite cumbersome, so I tried using the following:

```
m = m[np.all(~np.isinf(m),axis=1)]
```

This works great when finding and deleting a row of all `infs`, but when I try the following to find and delete all columns that contain all `infs`, the method runs into problems,

```
m = np.array([[1,2,np.inf,4],
                        [5,6,np.inf,8],
                        [9,10,np.inf,12]])

m = m[np.all(~np.isinf(m),axis=0)]
```

giving the following error

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 4
```

I had thought that using `axis=1` would search along each row, and `axis=0` would search along each column, but it seems that I might not understand how the use of `axis` works. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace the line that throws an error with this one:

```
m = m[:, np.all(~np.isinf(m),axis=0)]
```